# I wrote a naughts and crosses game in Python, but the winner isn't being declared properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the code for the game:

```
# oxo_main_shell.py
# code needed to test integrity of main shell
player = "X"
oxo = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
win = ""
turns = 9

# main shell
def setup():
    global win, player, turns, oxo, good, allwins
    win = ""
    player = "X"
    turns = 9
    oxo = [" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    good = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    allwins = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]

def msgintro():
    msg = "Press [Enter] to continue"
    print(msg)
    input()

def printrow(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    print(a+' '+b+' |'+c+' '+d+' |'+e+' '+f+' ')

def printline():
    print('-----+-----+-----')

def printboard(oxo):
    printrow('1 ',' ','2 ',' ','3 ',' ')
    printrow('  ',oxo[0],'  ',oxo[1],'  ',oxo[2])
    printrow('  ',' ','  ',' ','  ',' ')
    printline()
    printrow('4 ',' ','5 ',' ','6 ',' ')
    printrow('  ',oxo[3],'  ',oxo[4],'  ',oxo[5])
    printrow('  ',' ','  ',' ','  ',' ')
    printline()
    printrow('7 ',' ','8 ',' ','9 ',' ')
    printrow('  ',oxo[6],'  ',oxo[7],'  ',oxo[8])
    printrow('  ',' ','  ',' ','  ',' ')

def play():
    pos = 0
    while pos not in good:
        pos = input()
        try:
            pos = int(pos)
        except ValueError:
            pos = 0
    oxo[pos-1] = player
    good.remove(pos)

def getplaces(player,oxo):
    places = []
    for i in range(0,len(oxo)):
        if player == oxo[i]: places.append(i+1)
    return places

def issubset(win,places):
    for i in range(0,len(places)-2):
        if win == places[i:i+3]: return True
    return False

def checkwin(player,oxo):
    places = getplaces(player,oxo)
    for win in allwins:
        if issubset(win,places): return True
    return False

def swap(player):
    if player == 'X': return '0'
    return 'X'

def declarewinner(win):
    if win != "":
        print(win,"wins")
    else:
        print("Stalemate")

# main program
setup()
msgintro()
printboard(oxo)

# turn
while turns > 0:
    play()
    printboard(oxo)
    if checkwin(player,oxo): break
    player = swap(player)
    turns -= 1
declarewinner(player)
```

It mostly works, letting me put pieces in the positions when I input the position number and declaring a winner properly if the board is not filled by the end of the game. If the board is filled by the end of the game, however, then it starts declaring the winner incorrectly and it a stalemate is never declared. For example, I tested a game with the pieces in these positions:

```
1    |2    |3    
   X |   0 |   X 
     |     |     
-----+-----+-----
4    |5    |6    
   X |   0 |   0 
     |     |     
-----+-----+-----
7    |8    |9    
   0 |   X |   X 
     |     |
```

This should have been a stalemate, but 0 was declared the winner.

Another example is in a game with the pieces in these positions:

```
1    |2    |3    
   X |   0 |   X 
     |     |     
-----+-----+-----
4    |5    |6    
   0 |   X |   0 
     |     |     
-----+-----+-----
7    |8    |9    
   0 |   X |   X 
     |     |
```

0 is declared the winner, when X should be declared the winner.

Is there any way for me to make it so the winner is correctly declared?

Comment: Why are you checking for `subset(win, places)`? I think the main error is that allwins is 1-indexed while it should be 0-indexed, the first winning combination is by fields 0, 1, and 2.

Comment: I made a tic tac toe game not too long ago and this part of debugging can be kinda tricky. I think that your error is probably coming from your `getplaces` method not working properly. What does it print out each iteration? Is it the same as what's on the board that gets printed out?

Comment: Each iteration the current pieces that have been placed are shown on the board. For example before the third turn the board will have 2 pieces on it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the main game loop, at the end of the posted code.

If you fill out the board completely but nobody wins, the game exits the while loop but no `checkwin` is performed after the loop exits, and whoever was player when the loop ended automatcially wins due to `declarewinner(player)`. Thus, in a stalemate 0 always wins.

Same thing if you win on the last move before filling the game board. No `checkwin`, 0 always wins.

So, just add some `checkwin` at the end. Replace the last line with:

```
if checkwin("0", oxo):
    declarewinner("0")
elif checkwin("X", oxo):
    declarewinner("X")
else: # stalemate
    declarewinner("")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from you calling `declarewinner(player)` at the end. `declarewinner` function will declare a stalemate only if the variable passed in is an empty string. But since your `player` variable is set for every turn, it will never be an empty string.

What you want instead is to set the global `win` variable in `checkwin` when a win has occured. Then, modify your `declarewinner` function to read from the global `win` variable, as opposed to taking in an argument.

Example:

```
def checkwin(player,oxo):
    global win  # since you are modifying a global variable
    places = getplaces(player,oxo)
    for w in allwins:  # use `w` instead of `win` to avoid namespace collision with your global variable
        if issubset(w,places):
            win = player  # set the `win` variable as to your winning player 
            return True
    return False

...

def declarewinner():
    if win != "":
        print(win,"wins")
    else:
        print("Stalemate")

...

while turns > 0:
    play()
    printboard(oxo)
    if checkwin(player,oxo): break
    player = swap(player)
    turns -= 1
declarewinner()
```